# Configure how ClientContext is resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am working on a project where we are abstracting the access to SharePoint-stored data using a repository pattern, as follows (details omitted for brevity):

```
    public interface IDocumentRepository { ... }
    public class SharePointDocumentRepository: IDocumentRepository
    {
        public SharePointDocumentRepository(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

So, in order to be able to use an IDocumentRepository instance in the ASP.Net MVC app, in the UnityConfig.cs the container is configured as follows:

```
    ...
    container.RegisterType<IDocumentRepository, SharePointDocumentRepository>();
    ...
```

The problem is, that in runtime, I get the following exception:

> The type ClientContext has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable
>   to disambiguate.

In order to fix this, I need to register how the ClientContext should be resolved. So far, I have tried the following, without any success:

1. configure the use of the constructor, which has a string parameter
2. configure Unity to return a specific instance, whenever a ClientContext is required

So, my question is: is there a way to configure Unity to resolve the ClientContext, or should I fall back to injecting it through a property of the IDocumentRepository interface, whenever I get an instance of this interface? NB: The second approach will make the SharePoint repository har to use in any other components, which have no access to the HTTP context, so it is not a preferable one.

Remark: creating an instance of the repository without DI could be done as follows:

```
    ...
    [SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SharePointContext spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
        using(var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            var documentRepository = new SharePointDocumentRepository(clientContext);
            ...
        }
        ...
        return View();
    }
```

Note, that `SharePointContextFilterAttribute`, `SharePointContextProvider`, and `SharePointContext` are auto-generated when a project is created from the "Apps for SharePoint" project template.

Comment: If you were creating your `SharePointDocumentRepository` and `ClientContext` by hand, how would you do this? Can you add that code to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your controller depends on `IDocumentRepository`, but such dependency needs to be created based on some context that can only be obtained from inside the controller action it self. Correct?

If this is the case, then you need to use a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

In your case, your factory should look something like this:

```
public interface IDocumentRepositoryFactory
{
    IDocumentRepository Create(Context context);
}

public class SharePointDocumentRepositoryFactory : IDocumentRepositoryFactory
{
    public IDocumentRepository Create(Context context)
    {
        //Create the repository
        SharePointContext spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(....);
        using(var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            return new SharePointDocumentRepository(clientContext); 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that here I am using `Context` as an input to the `Create` method. You should replace this with whatever context you need from your controller to be able to construct the repository (if any).

Now, change the constructor of your controller to accept `IDocumentRepositoryFactory` in the constructor and store it in a field.

And don't forget to register the factory like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDocumentRepositoryFactory, SharePointDocumentRepositoryFactory>();
```

Then in your action, you can use factory to create the repository like this:

```
var repository = m_DocumentRepositoryFactory.Create(....);
```

Where `m_DocumentRepositoryFactory` is the name of the field that you used to store the factory dependency in the constructor.

**Update:**

Since the `ClientContext` class is disposable, then it does not make sense to return `SharePointDocumentRepository` after we dispose of `ClientContext`.

I suggest that you use an Isolation Factory instead. Like this:

```
public interface IDocumentRepositoryIsolationFactory
{
    void CreateAndUse(Context context, Action<IDocumentRepository> action);
}

public class SharePointDocumentRepositoryIsolationFactory : IDocumentRepositoryIsolationFactory
{
    public void CreateAndUse(Context context, Action<IDocumentRepository> action)
    {
        //Create the repository
        SharePointContext spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(....);
        using(var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            var repository = SharePointDocumentRepository(clientContext); 

            action(repository);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this in your action:

```
m_IsolationFactory.CreateAndUse(... , (repository) =>
{
    //repository is a IDocumentRepository, use it here

});
```

Comment: The first proposed solution did the job. The isolation factory is not needed, since the context is dependency to the factory i.e. it is constructed, passed to the factory, and disposed by the caller. In my case this is the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an instance of ClientContext to the constructor as such:

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext();
container.RegisterInstance<ClientContext>("myContext", clientContext);

container.RegisterType<IDocumentRepository, SharePointDocumentRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<ClientContext>("myContext")));
```

Comment: Two problems with this approach: 1) ClientContext has no default constructor, both its constructors require the URL of the SP site (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.clientcontext.aspx), 2) the only place where we can get the URL of the SP site is the controller. Is it possible to also access the unity container from there?

Comment: You could probably access the url of the SP site through HttpContext - (which is not accessible in UnityConfig yet).
You could solve this by providing a factory in between, accepting a lazy loading parameter to retrieve the httpcontext when possible. Not the prettiest approach though :/